# POST to PHP API using Ionic httpClient doesnt send any data

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

Im new to this forum,

I have an Ionic project and use Php APIs,

Now i am trying to turn my existing APIs into one class with several functions, there is a router that redirects to the Class file and calls the right functions, it works with postman and with data sent from ajax, but not with Ionic.
have been trying to post json from Ionic to my new API and got blocked by CORS policy:

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json" });
    const dados = {
      'data': 'test'
    };
let response2 = this.httpClient.post("https://localhost/api/login", dados, { headers: 
headers}).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
```

Tryed again with:

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json,text/plain');
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('data', 'test')
      console.log(dados)
    let requestOptions = { headers: headers, params: params }
    this.httpClient.post("https://localhost/api/login", null, requestOptions).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.loading.loadingDismiss();
    })
```

And it receives data all right from the API, but the API doesnt receive any data from Ionic.

The function i call is:

```
public function login($post_data): void
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Accept: application/json');
    $data['a']='a';
    $data['data']=$post_data;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And when i call it from another source it returns all righ:

```
{'a'='a', 
'data' = {...}
}
```

But when i call it from Ionic it returns:

```
{'a'='a',
'data' = [ ]
}
```

As if no data was received

(OBS: When i try to pass data in the null field it gets blocked by CORS)

Comment: When i am working with ionic and php, i always create a php file for each functionality. So in ionic i do: this.http.post("http://localhost/project/file.php",this.formGroup.value).subscribe()... and then in php i put first the headers then i make a json decode.

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type ,X-Auth-Token , Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');$userData=file_get_contents("php://input");
$data=json_decode($userData);
$username=$data->username;
$password=$data->password;

Comment: It always works for me. Hope this will help.